# typescript class method definition using interface

Tags: typescript

I have a interface export from other package, and I need to implement it using class. However typescript can not auto infer the parameter type. Is there any way to get the method parameter automatically by ts ?

```js
interface Interface {
    hello(param: {a: number}): void
}

class A implements Interface {
    hello(param) { // param is any
// how can i get the param type automatically ？ 
    }
}


const B : Interface  = {
    hello(param) {// {a: number}

    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it's related, but typescript allows defining a different signature for the class: [playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJLmvJyDeAoZQ5ACwgBsyB7ACgAc4o4BbALlzjZAFcmAjaAL4BKNgDdKwACZ4BePAjJwAzkuQBBZMCa0yEJhHCr0kWIhT4iJclToNmbHB2Tc+0ADTJebXpUq64IMK4yLKy8pQgSmDIML7IALzOEADu6tRCeLGUAHSkFDQ4yE4AzCEZCBFRngxsxphmCTG+eLwMudYFRWylwkA). Maybe (!) that's the reason it wants you to be explicit

Answer (score 1):

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#cautions mentions this very issue. Quoting directly from the docs:

> A common source of error is to assume that an implements clause will change the class type - it doesn’t!

```
interface Checkable {
  check(name: string): boolean;
}
 
class NameChecker implements Checkable {
  check(s) {
// Parameter 's' implicitly has an 'any' type.

    // Notice no error here
    return s.toLowercse() === "ok";
                 
// any
  }
}
```

> In this example, we perhaps expected that `s`’s type would be influenced by the `name: string` parameter of check. It is not - `implements` clauses don’t change how the class body is checked or its type inferred.